# nginx is giving me 403 forbidden on index.html, permissions are correct, config is copied from another server

Tags: nginx

So, nginx is giving me a 403 Forbidden error page when I try to hit http://mayall.syniq.co.uk which should spit out a tribute page to Rik Mayall, as does http://byrne.syniq.co.uk (shouldn't take you long to guess my naming scheme :) ).

namei -l /www/vhosts/mayall.syniq.co.uk/public/index.html yields the following:

```
f: /www/vhosts/mayall.syniq.co.uk/public/index.html
drwxr-xr-x root     root     /
drwxr-xr-x www-data www-data www
drwxr-xr-x www-data www-data vhosts
drwxr-xr-x www-data www-data mayall.syniq.co.uk
drwxr-xr-x www-data www-data public
-rw-r--r-- www-data www-data index.html
```

So it's not the permissions. My vhost config is as follows:

```
server {
    listen *:80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name mayall.syniq.co.uk;

    # Character Set
    charset utf-8;

    # Logs
    access_log /www/vhosts/mayall.syniq.co.uk/logs/access_log.nginx;
    error_log /www/vhosts/mayall.syniq.co.uk/logs/error_log.nginx;

    # Directory Indexes
    index index.html index.htm;

    root /www/vhosts/mayall.syniq.co.uk/public;
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { log_not_found off; access_log off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { log_not_found off; access_log off; }

    # Block access to .htaccess
    location ~ \.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

This is what appears in the logs:

```
2014/10/01 18:58:20 [error] 20957#0: *1 access forbidden by rule, client: 31.49.162.112, server: mayall.syniq.co.uk, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "mayall.syniq.co.uk"
2014/10/01 18:58:30 [error] 20957#0: *1 access forbidden by rule, client: 31.49.162.112, server: mayall.syniq.co.uk, request: "GET /index.html HTTP/1.1", host: "mayall.syniq.co.uk"
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What's nginx.conf content ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, one of the guys in #nginx on freenode pointed this out for me, but I guess he didn't want to post the answer in here.

The reason I'm getting the 403 is because the `location ~ \.ht` block is matching the `.ht` in `index.html`, and thus incorrectly correctly blocking the request.

Fix is simply to add a `/` before the . as follows:

```
location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
}
```